# How to add custom selected focus class to list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add custom "selected focus" class to list items where the data-value is 4 using jquery in the following code.

```
 <ul class="list">
   <li data-value="5" class="option selected focus">Bootstrap 4.3.1</li>
   <li data-value="3" class="option">Bootstrap 4.1.1</li>
   <li data-value="1" class="option">Bootstrap 4.0.0</li>
   <li data-value="2" class="option">Bootstrap 3.3.0</li>
   <li data-value="4" class="option">Bootstrap 3.0.0</li>
   <li data-value="6" class="option">No Bootstrap</li>
 </ul>
```

I tried

```
$('.list').childern('li').attr('selected');
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? `$('.list li[data-value=4]').addClass("selected focus")` maybe?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it worked but how to remove selected focus from other list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first remove class from all of options, then add it to one

```js
$('.list').find('li').removeClass('selected focus');
$('.list').find('li[data-value=4]').addClass('selected focus');
```

```css
.selected.focus {
 color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
   <li data-value="5" class="option selected focus">Bootstrap 4.3.1</li>
   <li data-value="3" class="option">Bootstrap 4.1.1</li>
   <li data-value="1" class="option">Bootstrap 4.0.0</li>
   <li data-value="2" class="option">Bootstrap 3.3.0</li>
   <li data-value="4" class="option">Bootstrap 3.0.0</li>
   <li data-value="6" class="option">No Bootstrap</li>
 </ul>
```